# Using a bluetooth headset as both audio and mic on a raspberry pi

Tags: audio, bluetooth, pi-3b+, microphone

I am looking to purchase a Bluetooth headset for a project of mine and I would love it if I could use it with my raspberry pi

The headset I am looking to get is this one:

https://www.gearbest.com/earbud-headphones/pp_575328.html

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 model B+

Can somebody tell me if this is gonna work and if not what other alternatives I have to do wireless?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [website](https://www.gearbest.com/earbud-headphones/pp_575328.html) you linked, the headset supports the following profiles:

- `A2DP`: allows multimedia audio to be streamed to a headset
- `AVRCP`
- `HFP`
- `HSP`: for audio communication with a headset

In [this tutorial](https://youness.net/raspberry-pi/how-to-connect-bluetooth-headset-or-speaker-to-raspberry-pi-3#comment-8363) it is suggested to use BT USB dongle to bypass the RPi's BCM43438 wireless chip. That way you can use the `A2DP` and `HSP` profiles.

Comment: The author's description in [that tutorial](https://youness.net/raspberry-pi/how-to-connect-bluetooth-headset-or-speaker-to-raspberry-pi-3) is a bit ambiguous IMHO. Quoting the author: [`The aim of post is to not use external Bluetooth dongle`](https://youness.net/raspberry-pi/how-to-connect-bluetooth-headset-or-speaker-to-raspberry-pi-3#comment-3147). Ambiguities aside though, after reading the tutorial, RPi 3B+ owners will be disappointed in their BT hardware - at least I was. This is rant-worthy... there should have been a disclosure from "The Foundation".

Comment: @Seamus Simultaneous WiFi/BT usage is a problem on many cheap (and some not so cheap, I'm looking at you, Lenovo!) laptops as well. In laptops this is usually solved by fitting in a second 2.4GHz antenna, but this is not an option on RPi since there's no antenna connector.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev: AFAIC, the issue isn't cost. It's simply respecting the members of the community enough to make a disclosure.